# How i can apply water mark on many images in a single click

Tags: jpeg

I have a large collection of Books. I have all pages in JPEG format. I want to apply a text of My website transparent on each page. I have made an image by the help of Adobe photo shop. But its very difficult for me to apply on each page as it will take alot of time. If anyone can suggest me for a software that could solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Tom,

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop, you need to "Record" the action of you watermarking one and then you can apply that same action to a number of photos. It might not be super fast, but it'll automatically do the work for you. This talks more about it: http://photoshop911.typepad.com/help/2004/04/watermarking_ph.html

Also, if you Google Batch Watermark Photos in Photoshop, you'll get a ton of tutorials.

**EDIT**: No problem. Also, this might actually be a much easier tutorial to follow and it contains images - that usually helps me anyway :)  http://www.showandtell-graphics.com/batch-signature.html
Glad to have helped answer your question. I know Photoshop can be amazing, but harder than heck to use sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong place to ask, voted to move to superuser.
Anyway, you might want to look at ImageMagick, if you are not afraid of the command line.

Comment: This would be my choice too - I once set up some scripts for Imagemagick for a photo agency to create thumbnails for their stock images and also to produce copies with a watermark - it whizzes through whole folders in no time at all. Sadly I don't have copies but the commands weren't complex and there's online howtos for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) for it. Use the Batch conversion. There is an option to insert text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had similar issue I had. I tried photoshop record and did not work and could not find an app positioning the text properly for photos whatever the width/height ratio is.
So, I created myself to handle for my hundreds of photos for blogging and web post optimization.

Please take a look "Bulk Photo Editor" from MS app store:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bulk-photo-editor/9ndrgzv0rbtm#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Help: https://skyontheway.com/2018/09/10/free-bulk-photo-editor-how-to-guide/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [XNconvert](http://www.xnconvert.com/) to add a watermark quickly

- can add transparent watermarks
- can process thousands of files with a single click
- watermark position and opacity can be adjusted
- tool is portable (follow [these instructions](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2080) on how to create a xnconvert.ini)
  [image]

**Note:** You need to create a template watermark file once.